# External function calling for parent's "this" scope

Tags: scope, ecmascript-6, this, es6-class, es6-modules

I have two .js files: root.js and external.js

root.js

```
import myExternalFunction from 'external.js'

class Parent {
    constructor(){}
    parentFunction = () => {
        console.log('I was called from an external function using "this."')
    }
}
```

external.js

```
export default myExternalFunction = () => {
    this.parentFunction()
}
```

Currently I receive an error about it not being a function, or no access to 'this'.

How do I import external functions that want to use the 'this' scope from which they are being called?

Comment: That's invalid JS, you cannot have an arrow function inside a `class`.

Comment: Given that `myExternalFunction` isn't passed an instance of `Parent`, what specifically are you expecting? How is it supposed to know what `parentFunction` you want called?

Comment: @Bergi I use arrow functions in classes on a regular basis, and it works plainly.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I don't want my external function to know about my `Parent`  When my Parent imports this external function, I want it to be able to use it. Kind of like prototyping a method, or using a functional utility library like underscore.


I want the `Parent` to call this imported function `myExternalFunction`, and have the function be aware of "this" scope, since it's now imported. I have also tried `myImportedFunction = myExternalFunction` in `Parent`, but it didn't work.

Comment: @sadhucoder Well it's not an ES6 `class` for sure, however there exist babel plugins for experimental syntax that moves property assignments outside of the constructor

Comment: Arrow functions called with `obj.fn()` explicitly don't use the value of `this` from `obj` so the value of `this` will be the lexical `this`, not the object `this`.  Stop using arrow functions for methods of an object.

Comment: @Bergi Gotcha. I could see a Babel transform changing things in a way I don't understand yet. I'll look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I import external functions that want to use the 'this' scope from which they are being called?

It doesn't have anything to do with how you export/import the function.

There are two things you need to consider:

- functions that want to receive their `this` value dynamically [must not be arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572), so use

  ```
  export default function myExternalFunction() {
      this.parentFunction()
  }
  ```
- [as usual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572), the function must be invoked in the right way to get the expected `this` value. There's no magic that passes the current `this` value in the scope of the call to the called function. You'll have to do something like

  ```
  import myExternalFunction from 'external.js'

  class Parent {
      constructor(){
          this.method = myExternalFunction;
          this.parentFunction = () => {
              console.log('I was called from an external function using "this."')
          }
      }
  }

  const example = new Parent;
  example.method() // an invocation as a method
  myExternalFunction.call(example); // explicit using `call`
  ```